# Find regular polygon vertices by any given number of sides and then center it inside an square

Tags: c++, geometry

I'm drawing a polygon by getting the points of it's vertices like this

```
std::vector<double> polygonPoints(int numberOfSides, double radius) {
  std::vector<double> coordinates;
  double d = 3 / 4.0;

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSides; i++) {
    double t = 2 * M_PI * ((double)i / numberOfSides + d);
    double x = cos(t) * radius + radius;
    double y = sin(t) * radius + radius;
    coordinates.push_back(x);
    coordinates.push_back(y);
  }

  return coordinates;
}
```

The result for a pentagon looks like this

[image]

And for an hexagon looks like this

[image]

I'm happy with the result of the hexagon but the pentagon it's not getting centred inside the rectangle.

To build this polygons I'm passing half of the side of the rectangle that contains the polygon as the radius for the poligonPoints function.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the solution. I just had to find the difference between the radius of the circumcircle and the apothem of the polygon, then divide it by two and add it to all the y coordinates when the polygon has an odd number of sides.

```
std::vector<double> polygonPoints(int numberOfSides, double radius) {
  std::vector<double> coordinates;
  double angle = 3 / 4.0;
  double apothem = radius * cos(M_PI / (double)numberOfSides);
  double yTopOffset =
    helpers::isEven(numberOfSides) ? 0.0 : (radius - apothem) / 2.0;

  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSides; i++) {
    double t = 2 * M_PI * ((double)i / (double)numberOfSides + angle);
    double x = cos(t) * radius + radius;
    double y = sin(t) * radius + radius + yTopOffset;
    coordinates.push_back(x);
    coordinates.push_back(y);
  }

  return coordinates;
}
```

[image]

with this now it's easy to make smaller polygons and center them inside the square

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although I understand your way of working with the apotheum of the polygon, there's a far simplier approach:

Calculate the center of the polygon you have obtained:

```
Ycp = (Y1 + Y2 + ... + Yn) / n
```

Now imagine the center you want to meet is `(Xc, Yc)`, then you just move your polygon following the Y-axis, using the distance `(Yc - Ycp)`. It takes a bit more calculating but it's far more straightforward.

Comment: Oh thanks, what is Y here? I'm not sure how your solution will be with code

Comment: By Y I just mean the Y-coordinate. From the drawings, I have the impression that the X-coordinate of the centre is correct, only the Y-coordinate seems to be off. As far as the code is concerned, you might just use the `for`-loop you already have in the question.